# Creating raster basemap for web application?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, basemap

I'm sure this is probably a common problem and many have already found the right answer.

I have a large mosaic raster file (a city's ortophoto) in .ecw fromat  and we want to use it as a basemap in a web application. Due to its size (2GB) rendering is very slow, therefore increasing performance is vital.

1) My first option was importing the raster in our ArcSDE geodatabase (on postgreSQL)-> build pyramids-> then publishing it as a map service with a 5 scale cache on our ArcGIS Server. Failed for unknown reasons (so far).

2) The second option would be importing the raster in the ArcSDE GDB then->create pyramids-> publish it as an image service to ArcGIS Server.

3) Third option would be to keep the raster in the folder-->copy the raster to the server --> publish it as an image service.

4) Fourth option would be to save the raster as a layer file-> then publish it in a map service.

Which of these four options would be the best when talking about rendering speed?

I use ArcGIS 10.1 + POstgreSQL DB + ArcGIS Server Enteprise 10.1

---

As brenth was saying you cannot publish an .ecw. I do have all the tiff files that created the .ecw mosaic, so I will try to create a mosaic from them and then publish using the fourth method. Does it sound ok?

Comment: #4 is best and least work but costs money because Intergraph requires a license to use ECW's in Map Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go (4). In the web map service publication window, it is possible to specify a tiling scheme and trigger automatically the tiles pyramid after the service publication.

[image]

Comment: hey. first of all thanks for the very quick reply.tried 4. i added the layer in arcmap-> share as service-> service editor-> created my own tile scheme (with 4 scales)-> publish--> ERRor 001369: Failed to create the service. Packaging succeded, but publishing failed

Comment: # 4 is how we do it as well.  Put it in a layer, make a service and cache.  It works really well, BUT - the caveat is you have to go to Intergraph and buy a license to use the ECW's in ArcGIS Server.  It's about $1000 per 4 cores - but you can talk to their salesmen and get a deal perhaps.

Comment: brenth you are totally right: "This format can be used in ArcGIS for Desktop, but when publishing, you require the ECW for ArcGIS for Server extension from ERDAS". So this is probably why I couldn't pushlish it. I also have the tif files that created the .ecw. I will create a mosaic from them , and then try to publish it.

Comment: since the .ecw format is no longer an option. what would be the best format and the best compression in your opinion? So far I've created a .tif mosaic.

Comment: So far I use tif format with LZW compression and I am happy with that!

Comment: Hi Julien, did that but it's still quite big, and I also did a .png with jpeg compression and it's smaller. They look quite the same to me. Do you think I can encounter problems if I use a .png or a .jpg with a lossy compression?

Answer (score 0):

**Standalone Map Tiler 'MapCruncher' from Microsoft** (originally for Bing Maps)

This will cut up any image for use for in any web mapping using raster tiling..

> *Have you ever looked at satellite photos of a building in Virtual Earth -- and wished you could zoom right in and see its floorplan?
>   Have you ever used VE to plan a trip across town -- and wanted to
>   seamlessly switch from its road maps to maps of bicycle trails, bus
>   routes, or carpool lanes? Have you ever wanted to create and publish
>   your own map mashups -- and wished you had a tool to make it easy to
>   integrate a map you care about into Virtual Earth? With MapCruncher,
>   you can!*

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mapcruncher/